# Traveling to US on K3 visa

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration

I am travelling to the U.S. on a k-3 visa for the first time.  Can fly Etihad Airways on a flight that will be pre-cleared in Abu Dhabi? Is the first-time immigration processing be done at Abu Dhabi?

Comment: Pre-clearance is the term for the customs checks done in Abu Dhabi. Pre-screening is something else. I've edited, but feel free to re-edit if you didn't mean that.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Etihad's website on this subject](https://www.etihad.com/en/fly-etihad/us-immigration-in-abu-dhabi), once you clear US Customs and immigrations for the US at Abu Dhabi airport, there is no need for further checks when you arrive in the US.

> ### US Customs and Border Protection (CBP) facility in Abu Dhabi
>
> The United States Customs and Border Protection (CBP) facility at Terminal
>   3 (T3) in Abu Dhabi Airport is a purpose-built facility that allows US
>   bound passengers to process all immigration, customs and agriculture
>   inspections in Abu Dhabi, before you depart. It is the only CBP
>   facility in the Middle East, and one of only a few outside of North
>   America.
>
> After you have cleared customs and immigrations for the US at Abu
>   Dhabi airport, there is no need for further checks when you arrive in
>   the US. You can even check your baggage through to your final
>   destination in the US.
>
> It’s the fastest way to get through the airport and on to your final
>   destination in the US – your way.